# Display the Field of a lookup object in PageBlockTable, Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have two objects Fruit__c and Apple__c. Apple__C has a lookup to Fruit__c.

Now, I am writing a Visualforce page, where in the page block table I want the columns to be

Fruit__c.Name
Fruit__c.Color
(If Fruit has an Apple, then) Apple__c.ExpiryDate (Since, Fruit can have multiple Apples, I want to get the Apple with the latest expiry date)

I am trying to understand, how to display the Apple__c.ExpiryDate in the PageBlockTable, when my controller is on Fruit__c.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you make the relationship between Fruit__c and Apple__c a master-detail one, then you can add a [rollup summary field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US) on Fruit__c which is the maximum value of Apple__c.ExpiryDate. That then makes you Visualforce page simple to write as you are only displaying the values from the Fruit__c object.

It is certainly possible to create your page without this model change, but you will probably need to use techniques like [aggregate queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm), [relationship queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm), and wrapper objects (really just simple Apex classes that hold data) to get it done which adds complication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running out of rollup summaries, it's not hard to create a SOQL query that retrieves the latest Apple__c for your fruit object.

You'd go something like this:

```
Fruit[] frooties {public get; private set;}

frooties = [SELECT Id, Name, Color, (
               SELECT Id, FruitId, Name, ExpiryDate
               FROM Apples__r
               ORDER BY ExpiryDate DESC)
            FROM Fruit__c];
```

Then to display you just need to handle the fact that you now have a list of apples that can have a length of 0:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!frooties}" var="froot">
.... other fruit columns...
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">Freshest Apple!</apex:facet>
    <apex:outputText rendered="{!IF(froot.Apples__r.size > 0, true, false)}">
        {!froot.Apples__r[0].ExpiryDate}"/>
    </apex:outputText>
</apex:column>
```